# std::accumulate won't' perform sum of elements with std::plus functor

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I have a class which contains an integer among some other things:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x)
        :
        x(x)
    {}
    int operator+(const Foo& rhs)
    {
        return x + rhs.x;
    }
private:
    int x;
    float whatever = 0.0f;
};
```

I also have a vector of these objects:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

now, what I wanted to do was to use **std::accumulate** with the **std::plus** functor (or maybe some other STL function) to sum the X values of all elements in the vector, here's what I tried:

```
int sum = std::accumulate(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 0, std::plus<int>{});
```

But i'm getting a compiler error

**Error C2440: "'initializing' : cannot convert from 'type1' to 'type2'
'conversion' : cannot convert from 'type1' to 'type2'"**

what am i doing wrong, how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: yes you cannot add `int` to `Foo`.

Comment: `std::plus<int>{}` is a function object that can add two `int`s.  It will not operate on a `Foo`.  And `int operator+(const Foo& rhs)` should probably be `int operator+(const Foo& rhs) const`.  It would be unusual to specify that the right argument is `const` while the left argument is not.

Comment: From the documentation for std::plus, one possible implementation would be constexpr Foo operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const { return lhs + rhs; }

Comment: ok I changed it std::plus<Foo> and fixed the operator+ as suggested but i'm still getting the same error C2440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add an `int` and a `Foo` with a function that takes two `Foo`s.

You could use a function that adds `int` to `Foo`:

```
// in Foo
friend int operator+(int lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.x;
}
```

Or you could use a function that adds two `Foo`s

```
// in Foo
Foo operator+(const Foo& rhs)
{
    return { x + rhs.x };
}

// in main
Foo sum = std::accumulate(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo(0), std::plus<Foo>{});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement `operator+` as friend (free function), so `int` would auto convert to `Foo` in `int + Foo` (because the constructor)

---

and do not use `std::plus` since you're now adding `int` and `Foo`, `std::plus<T>` only add two `T` and only returns `T` (i.e. it only has `T operator()(const T&, const T&)const`)

---

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int x): x(x){}
    friend int operator+(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs){
        return lhs.x + rhs.x;
    }
private:
    int x;
    float whatever = 0.0f;
};


int f(){
    std::vector<Foo> foos{1, 2, 3, 4};
    // do not specify std::plus<int>
    // std::plus<Foo> would not work either since it returns `Foo`, not `int`
    return std::accumulate(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 0); 
}
```

Comment: thank you, i was not familiar with this use of friend for operators.

Comment: @Slava fwiw, you can also put the operator outside of class.

Comment: @Slava oh wait you need private field so it still need to be friend.